# Blazor conditionally open/close tags not supported?

Tags: blazor

I want to show portions of my Blazor server page within another content under some condition:

```
@if (DoOpenTag) {
    <ContainerTag>
}
<MyControl />
@if (DoOpenTag) {
    </ContainerTag>
}
```

Compiler seems to get completely lost here... I know I could do this:

```
@if (DoOpenTag) {
    <ContainerTag>
        <MyControl />        
    </ContainerTag>
}
else {
    <MyControl />
}
```

But the content has quite some code and this leads to code duplication which I'd rather avoid!

Is there any way to achieve what I want here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code block isn't allowed in Razor markup.

You can define your inner code block in a `Renderfragment` and then use it in the conditional statement.

Here's a simple example to show you how to do it.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="m-2 text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=SetShowBox>Toggle Box</button>
</div>

@if (showBox)
{
    <div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
        @InnerContent
    </div>
}
else
{
    @InnerContent
}

@code {
    private bool showBox = false;

    private void SetShowBox()
        => showBox = !showBox;

    private RenderFragment InnerContent => __builder =>
    {
        // This can be any Razor Markup block
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <div>Welcome to my Blazor Application</div>
    };
}
```

> Why does your first block cause an error?

Razor files are compiled into normal C# files by the Razor compiler.
The Razor compiler doesn't allow "misformed" markup in code blocks.  Your code could easily have a typo or logic that added the wrong closing tag.

Here's what gets emitted for the main block:

```
if (showBox)
{
    __builder.OpenElement(10, "div");
    __builder.AddAttribute(11, "class", "bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2");
    __builder.AddContent(12, InnerContent);
    __builder.CloseElement();
}
else
{
    __builder.AddContent(13, InnerContent);
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. As per my code not being allowed - can you point out why / what exaclty makes it not allowed?

Comment: See my revised answer on Why.

Comment: I wonder if that 13 shouldn't be 12. I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok I see - compiler checks for tags within a single code block - crystal clear!

Comment: @HenkHolterman - that code block is lifted straight out of *Pages_Index_razor.g.cs*.  I think the compiler just uses an incrementing counter to guarantee it never uses the same number twice.  The renderer doesn't care about missing numbers.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Not my code, the Razor compiler's!  Interesting point though.  If they were both 12, would the renderer recognise them as the same render frame and save it some time if `show` switches.